# Two-tier commits with git

Tags: git, github

I need to set up a pretty unique git workflow. We have a private GitHub repo that has a bunch of committers (group A), of which I am one. I would like to allow some others (group B) to commit code to it, but on these conditions:

1. Every commit must first be reviewed by me. Group A must never see a commit unless I let it through. (Bonus points if it's also possible to appoint someone in group B to review commits instead of me, granting them some kind of special privilege to do so.)
2. The identity of the committers in group B must never be revealed to group A. (Bonus points if it's also possible to hide the identities of people in group A from group B as well, though not strictly necessary.)
3. There must be no way for group B to circumvent conditions 1 or 2.

I don't have control over the usernames and emails that committers in either group A or B configure their git with, but I can tell group B which repo to commit to. I'm pretty sure part of the solution is to have group A always sees me as the author of group B's commits.

I've been thinking about using a second copy of the repo and having group B committing to it, with me somehow rebasing the commits into the master copy, but I can't see how to use git mirrors and rebasing to do this in a way that achieves all my objectives. (This solution also seems to fail the bonus objectives in conditions 1 & 2, since I'll be the only one who can do the rebasing, and group B will see the authors of the commits synced into the secondary repo copy. Ideally someone here will have an alternative solution that also solves these bonus objectives too.)

Any advice?

P.S. My git-fu is intermediate at best, so spelling out the actual git commands for your strategy would be *extremely* helpful and appreciated.

Comment: ............... why?

Comment: The situation is fairly complex to explain here, and will only add unnecessary distraction to the question and responses. I'd like to keep answers focused on the technicalities of how to make this happen, instead of debating when it's a good idea to do this. I appreciate your understanding.

Comment: I mainly ask because this seems far outside the bounds of what the creators of git ever envisioned (or wanted) it to be used for, and by extension far beyond what any user/expert of git would know about.  It seems less like you're trying to enact version control than conduct a rigorous double blind study.

Comment: That being said, you probably want people in group b to generate diffs of their changes, email them to you, and then you create an equivalent commit and push to the main repository when they pass muster.  Similar to how changes to the git repository [are suggested](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/SubmittingPatches#L120)

Comment: @Dannnno thanks for the suggestion and link. It seems that would be a very low tech way to deal with this, and I'm not even so clear on the actual steps involved, especially on how to do "then you create an equivalent commit". Isn't there anything more streamlined, using the merging power of git to my advantage? If not, can you please explain more about how to wrangle emailed diffs into a commit on group A's repo, and how to then update group B's clones? Thanks.

Comment: No clue.  That being said I have a few ideas, and when I get a chance today/tomorrow I'll see if I can flesh out an answer, or at least something to get you started.

Comment: I'd assume this is related to [your question over on PM](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/how-do-i-organize-a-team-of-shadow-software-developers-think-ghostwriters)?

Comment: @Dannnno thanks in advance for your help with this. Regarding the PM question, I'd rather not connect the two and risk distracting people. I'm very eager to find a way to use git to achieve the needed workflow and would greately appreciate the SO community's expertise in making it happen. Thanks again for your understanding.

Comment: @Dannnno any chance you can share your ideas about this? Would really appreciate any insight you may have on this problem, thanks!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to work out the kinks yet. It involves mirrors, generating diffs, and applying patches if you care.